# Google Pay API Integration for individual developer in Android

Tags: android, payment, google-pay

I am trying to integrate **Google Pay API** in android app in India. I am an individual developer and need to accept payment in the app.

1. Do I need to create a business account compulsorily to accept the payment? If yes, while creating business account, it asks for **GSTIN**.
2. Is GSTIN  mandatory, is there any way to work without GSTIN ?

I am referring google's [documentation and sample code](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/googlepay-business).

Comment: Yes, You have to create business account and GST no. without it you can not accept payment for your App.